# EasyMock matcher for class data type

Tags: java, easymock

I am having nightmares with the syntax for this and easymock:

```
public void foo(Class<?> clazz);

EasyMock.expects(object.foo(EasyMock.isA(???)));
```

What should I be putting if my argument is String.class?  I initially thought:

`EasyMock.isA(((Class<?>)(String.class)).getClass())`

Yet when I make the call foo(String.class) I get:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to verify a generic type that will be erased at runtime anyway.

Use a capture object instead:

```
Capture<Class<?>> classCapture = new Capture<Class<?>>();
EasyMock.expect(object.foo(EasyMock.capture(classCapture)));

// ... other test setup ...

Assert.assertEquals(classCapture.getValue(), String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will also work as an expect statement if you don't want to use a Capture:

```
EasyMock.expects(object.foo(EasyMock.isA(String.class.getClass())));
```

Comment: Won't `String.class.getClass()` always return `java.lang.Class` ?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  `String.class.getClass()` will always return `java.lang.Class`.  Not sure what I was thinking.  Using a Capture as suggested in the answer @artbristol provided is the way to go.