# easymock missing behavior definition

Tags: easymock

i m writing test using easymock,  and i created the following mock object for my test,

```
auditor = createMock(Auditor.class);
auditor.start(isA(Audit.class)); //record
replay(auditor);
expect(auditor.getAudit("my-process")).andReturn(null);
replay(auditor);
```

Auditor class has a method 'start(Audit.class)', i recorded it first, then stub its other method 'getAudit()', then replay them all. however it complained:missing behavior definition from previous call start(isA(Audit.class)), what did i do wrong here? thanks,

Comment: The `isA` matcher is telling the expectation that the method will be called with an object of type Audit.class. From your description of the start method, it takes a class that is type Audit, not an object. So I think you want to change `isA` to `eq`. Also, you could try using a capture and then checking the class of the captured object as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467049/easymock-matcher-for-class-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the mock behavior for "auditor.start(...)" method incorrectly. Assuming it returns void, one way to do it would be:

```
@Test
public void testAuditor() {
    Auditor auditor = EasyMock.createMock(Auditor.class);
    auditor.start(Audit.class);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();  //record
    EasyMock.expect(auditor.getAudit("my-process")).andReturn(null);
    EasyMock.replay(auditor);

    //rest of your test code
}
```